# Hide Navigation Bar Forever

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

i am trying to hide navigation bar permanently i am using  immersive mode 
and sticky but when scrolling`` up or down  it appears again 
i know this question duplicate .

```
  View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

i read in google material cannot hide forever is this true 
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation
need suggest solutions

Comment: You can not do this without ADB or root.

Comment: @JediBurrell  did you mean device should be root 
can you give me example code

Comment: What phone is this done on? Navigation bar is outside you App, it's part of the Android OS, could be that the manifacturer has this behaviour coded in there flavour.

Comment: @HarounHajem
i need to full screen for ever

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it manually with ADB.
To put it permanently in immersive mode:

```
adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=*
```

To revert it: `adb shell settings put global policy_control null*`

To "remove" it, you can overscan it past the screen's view:

```
adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,-168
```

That number might have to be altered, but that's the one that worked for me.
To revert it: `adb shell wm 
0,0,0,0`

If you have to do it in your app, you can request root access and run the commands in the app:

```
val command = "settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=*"
val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
runtime.exec("su")
runtime.exec(command.split(" "))
```

Comment: i tried this code  still not working 
   try {
            String command ="settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=*";
           Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");;

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.split(" "));
            Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wm overscan 0,0,0,-168");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik You have to split the string by spaces, `exec` expects an array for each parameter. `("wm overscan 0,0,0,-168).split(" ")`

Comment: when i try 
adb shell settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=*  
adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,-168  
it remove from my all phone 
need only app 
i need to return it  a gain can you help me please to rturn it a gain

Comment: Edited the answer to include the reversions for both.

Comment: @ JediBurrell 
why not work  programmaticaly
can you write some java code in details

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik It should work, did you remove “adb shell” from the commands?

Comment: did you mean i should put in my app?

Comment: how i   add adb  shell  in my application

Comment: @mohammedragabmohammedborik You can't, when calling one of the commands you need to omitt that.

Comment: can you give me example in java

Comment: this my code   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,-168");
i try with split but nothing happen to my app

Comment: I'll have a Java example in a moment. Did you grant root access?

Comment: Oh, I just realized you're using "adb shell", remove that and split it. `runtime.exec(("wm overscan 0,0,0,-168").split(" "));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180385/discussion-between-jediburrell-and-mohammedragabmohammedborik).

Comment: wm overscan settings is problematic when app is in full screen mode